# Eclipse Plug-in Custom View Number of Markers

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, marker

I've created a new Eclipse plug-in that installs a new View.
After some operation I fill this View with Markers.

The View only shows the first 100 Markers as in the following image:

[Eclipse Markers http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/02/27/Markers.png](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/02/27/Markers.png)

How can I increase that 100 Markers limit ?

Here is how I implemented the View:

**plugin.xml:**

```
   <extension
         id="code_presentation.marker"
         name="Code Presentation Markers"
         point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers">
      <persistent
            value="true">
      </persistent>
      <super
            type="org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker">
      </super>
      <attribute
            name="owner">
      </attribute>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes">
      <type
            markerSeverity="0"
            markerType="code_presentation.marker"
            name="code_presentation.marker.type">

      </type>
   </extension>
  <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification">
      <specification
         annotationType="code_presentation.marker.type"
         colorPreferenceKey="code_presentation.marker.type.color"
         colorPreferenceValue="255,255,0"
         contributesToHeader="true"
         highlightPreferenceKey="code_presentation.marker.type.highlight"
         highlightPreferenceValue="false"
         includeOnPreferencePage="true"
         isGoToNextNavigationTargetKey="code_presentation.marker.type.nextnavigation"
         isGoToNextNavigationTarget="true"
         isGoToPreviousNavigationTargetKey="code_presentation.marker.type.previousnavigation"
         isGoToPreviousNavigationTarget = "true"
         icon="icons/Code_Presentation_Small.png"
         label="Qac error marker"
         overviewRulerPreferenceKey="code_presentation.marker.type.overview"
         overviewRulerPreferenceValue="true"
         presentationLayer="0"
         textPreferenceKey="code_presentation.marker.type.text"
         textPreferenceValue="false"
         textStylePreferenceValue="BOX"
         verticalRulerPreferenceKey="code_presentation.marker.type.ruler"
         verticalRulerPreferenceValue="true">
      </specification>
   </extension>
   <extension 
      point="org.eclipse.ui.views"> 
      <view 
         class="code_presentation.markersview.MyCustomMarkersView" 
         icon="icons/Code_Presentation_Small.png" 
         id="code_presentation.markersview.customMarker" 
         name="Code Presentation Markers"> 
      </view> 
   </extension>
   <extension 
      point="org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerSupport"> 
    <markerField 
      class="code_presentation.markersview.JustificationField" 
      id="code_presentation.markersview.Justificationfield" 
      name="Justification"> 
    </markerField>
    <markerContentGenerator 
      id="code_presentation.markersview.myCustomMarkerGenerator" 
      name="My Marker Generator"> 
       <markerTypeReference 
             id="code_presentation.marker"/>
       <markerFieldReference 
             id="org.eclipse.ui.ide.priorityField"/> 
       <markerFieldReference 
             id="org.eclipse.ui.ide.severityAndDescriptionField"/> 
       <markerFieldReference 
             id="org.eclipse.ui.ide.resourceField"/>
       <markerFieldReference 
             id="org.eclipse.ui.ide.locationField"/> 
       <markerFieldReference 
             id="code_presentation.markersview.justificationfield"/> 
    </markerContentGenerator>  
   </extension>
```

And I have **three java files** as in the following images:

[First File Code. http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/02/27/Untitled1z3Sd6.png](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/02/27/Untitled1z3Sd6.png)

[Second File Code. http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/02/27/Untitled2.png](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/02/27/Untitled2.png)

[Third File Code. http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/02/27/Untitled3.png](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/02/27/Untitled3.png)

Comment: We need more information than this. Is this a view you have written? Is it based on some existing view? The line at the top suggests you have a filter active which is limiting the contents.

Comment: I have updated the comment. Please let me know if make any redundant or necessary steps. Or if there is an easier way to achieve the same thing. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry I have updated the question* not the "comment" :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExtendedMarkersView get the number of limit from PreferenceStore. You have to change the value.

If you disable the limit of MarkerView, write code as follows:

```
    IDEWorkbenchPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().setValue(
            IDEInternalPreferences.USE_MARKER_LIMITS, false);
```

If you change the limit of MarkerView, write code as follows:

```
    IDEWorkbenchPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore()
            .setValue(IDEInternalPreferences.MARKER_LIMITS_VALUE, 200);
```

#### Attention:

When you change the value of PreferenceStore, all of the MarkerView's limit will be changed.
If you don't want to change it, you have to override ExtendedMarkersView#getStatusMessage on your own.

EDIT:

Add `org.eclipse.ui.ide` package to required plugins in your `plugin.xml` before using `IDEWorkbenchPlugin`.

[image: Add Required Plug-ins]

Comment: I have updated the question images links, as they were not shown in my side. Where exactly should I call that function? I called it in the constructor, but it didn't recognize `IDEWorkbenchPlugin`.

Comment: You can call it from [init](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/ntopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/part/ViewPart.html#init%28org.eclipse.ui.IViewSite%29) or [createPartControl](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/ntopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/part/WorkbenchPart.html#createPartControl%28org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite%29) method.

Comment: I tried this but `IDEWorkbenchPlugin` was not recognized. This is why I asked :)

Comment: Maybe you didn't add required plugin in your `plugin.xml`. I edited the answer.

Comment: In E4, another way to do this is to add the XML attribute markerLimitEnabled="false" to the root "view" XML element in the persistedState->memento value in your Application.e4xmi file. This has the advantage of only affecting your marker view.

Comment: You can also do this in the E3 manner by using a "preferencesCustomization" extension. Within your plugin_customization.ini file, add the following line (this assumes you have a custom view called com.example.product.application.view.problems):

    `org.eclipse.ui.ide/org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.CachedMarkerBuildercom.example.product.application.view.problems=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><prefs markerLimitEnabled="false"></prefs>`

The key/value declaration must all be on one line, and yes, the key ID is supposed to look smooshed together.

Answer (score 3):

The limit is set in `org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.MarkerContentGenerator` but this is an internal class so cannot be accessed directly.

The only thing that sets the limit is `org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.FiltersConfigurationDialog` which is also internal.

You can display this filters configuration dialog by adding a menu contribution for the command id `org.eclipse.ui.ide.configureFilters`.

This is the part of the Problems View plugin.xml menu definitions which links to the filters menu:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
   <menuContribution
        locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.views.ProblemView">
     <command
           commandId="org.eclipse.ui.ide.configureFilters"
           mnemonic="%command.configureFilters.mnemonic"
           style="push">
     </command>
  </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

You should be able to do something similar for your view.

Comment: I've understand your first two paragraph. Would you please give more detail about how to achieve the third one ?
I'm new to Eclipse plug-in development.

Comment: I have updated the question images links, as they were not shown in my side. I still don't understand your suggestion. I've put your code in my XML and I didn't notice any changes.